# python - read custom config file

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I parse and generate config files formatted like below with python? And the three section can be in different order.

```
#black_ip
8.8.4.4
10.10.10.10
#white_ip
8.8.8.8
#threshold
180.149.132.47:6000
```

UPDATE:

As for now, I resolved this by using the following re statement in python:

```
   SECTCION = re.compile(
    r'\#'               # start with `#`
    r'(?P<header>\w+)'  #
   )
```

and

```
OPTION = re.compile(
    r'\s*(?P<ip>((0|[1-9]\d?|[0-1]\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(0|[1-9]\d?|[0-1]\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))' # match the ip address
    r'(:)?'
    r'(?P<port>\d+)?\s*'    # match the port
)
```

these two statement will match them well. Then you need to do is to scan line by line and match them.

Comment: @cdarke I use `#\w+\s*((((2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?))(:\d+)?\s*)+` to match one section, but i have no idea how to extract them.

Comment: You are using capturing parentheses groups, you can capture them using the `groups()` method from the returned match object.

Comment: yes, that will extract. Now I have updated the description in the question to give my solution about this question.

Comment: @qiwihui: Whilst I appreciate that your code does what you want it to, it looks like a pig in a poke and a year from now you or anyone reading it, will struggle to work out what on earth is going on. Sometimes, it's worth taking the time to create code that is manageable, not just fit for the job at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), simple example as this:

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('sample.conf')

black_ip = config.get('all', 'black_ip')
white_ip = config.get('all', 'white_ip')
threshold = config.get('all', 'threshold')
print black_ip, white_ip, threshold
```

run result as this:

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ cat sample.conf 
[all]
black_ip=[8.8.4.4,10.10.10.10]
white_ip=8.8.8.8
threshold=180.149.132.47:6000

lo@ubuntu:~$ python demo.py 
[8.8.4.4,10.10.10.10] 8.8.8.8 180.149.132.47:6000
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out python-configobj it's available from the standard repositories, it will do everything that you could want for configuration files.
For example:

```
import os
from configobj import ConfigObj
configuration_dir = os.environ['HOME']
config_filename = configuration_dir + '/config.cfg'
if  os.access(config_filename, os.R_OK):
    pass
else:
    #if the file does not exist create and populate it
    cfg = ConfigObj(infile = config_filename, create_empty=True, write_empty_values=True, list_values=False)
    # define section control with a sub item in it
    cfg['control'] = {'TCP_PORT':'7000'}
    # define section Other with multiple sub items in it
    cfg['Other'] = {'parameter1':'','parameter2':''}
    cfg.write()

#Read the config file
cfg = ConfigObj(config_filename)
try:
    tcp_port = int(cfg['control']['TCP_PORT'])
    param1 = cfg['Other']['parameter1']
    param2 = cfg['Other']['parameter2']
except:
    tcp_port = 0
    param1 = ""
    param2 = ""
print tcp_port
print param1, param2

#Change the values in the config file
cfg['control']['TCP_PORT'] = '7000'
cfg['Other']['parameter1'] = 'parameter 1'
cfg['Other']['parameter2'] = 'parameter 2'
cfg.write()
print "Run program again to see changes"
```